# Internet Explorer Centering DIV issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I got some code which centers a div in a middle of the webpage. The code works great on chrome, but for some reason, on IE(I think it's 9 or 10) it works for the first time, and then it doesn't.

To demonstrate the issue, here are some photos: (Ignore the signs you don't understand, thats my language)

Chrome:

[image]

IE first time I click on an object to open up:

[image]

IE second time or more, when I click on an object to open up:

[image]

This is the code I'm using to center the div:

```
    jQuery.fn.center = function ()
{
    this.css("position","fixed");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
    return this;
}
```

The code that uses the `center()` function:

```
$('#products,#search-result').on("click",'.product-item-info',function() {
    var pid = $(this).find('input').val();
    $.get('product_info.php',{pid:pid},function(data){
        $('#product-lb').html(data).append('<span class="x"><span>X</span></span>');
        $('.x').click(function() {
            $('#dimmer').click();
        });

        $('#dimmer').css({width:$('html').width(),height:$('html').height()});
        $('#product-lb').center();
        $('#product-lb').show(800);
        $('#dimmer').show();
        $(window).resize(function() {
            $('#product-lb').center();
        });
    });
});
```

**explanations:**
`#products` is the div that contains all of the colorized divs in blue and green as you can see in the picture
`.product-item-info` is the class of the rectangle that can be found in each product DIV.
`#dimmer` is the black background
`#product-lb` is the div that has to be centered and shown on the page

I hope this is enough information! If you need more than this, please feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you fiddle this one or provide a link to your site?

Comment: @GaneshPandhere I will post a link to a demontration website. For some reason, my host is having difficulties at the momment, so it iwll take a few more minutes.

Comment: @GaneshPandhere Unfortunately, it appears that my shared-ip address is under DDOS attack, therefore, the shared-ip address is being filtered, it's going to take a while since I will be able to post a link here.

Comment: I think you need to add `+ "px"` to the end of your top and left css positions - `this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2) + "px");`

Comment: @Pete By your logic, why it worked on the first attempt? BTW, it didn't work

Comment: oh actually having looked at it again, do you wait until the image in the center is loaded before calculating the center position? it looks as if the second time it may have centered before the image  is loaded which is why the box is lower

Comment: @Pete 3 things, 1) I have no idea how to wait until it's loaded. 2)works prefectly fine on chrome 3)the div dones't need to wait for the image size inorder to set it's height since I've applied a css rule: `width:500px;
 height:400px;` for the image.

Comment: I'm only trying to help no need to get arsey about it and works perfectly in chrome doesn't mean it'll work in ie.  Ie has many annoying nuances that can cause scripts and css not to work

Comment: @Pete I'm sorry for sounding so offensive, I'm not trying to, apologizes. Thanks for your good will! BTW, you mentioned "waiting for the photo to load" Is there really a way to wait until the photo is loaded?

Comment: I use the following to preload the image and then fire a function once it is loaded: `$('.imageSelector').each(function () { if (this.complete) { imageLoaded.call(this); } else { $(this).one('load', imageLoaded); } });` where `imageLoaded` is the name of the function you want to run once the image has loaded

Comment: Didn't know such a thing at `complete` exists :o Thanks!

Comment: You could try using the following css: `{ top: 50%, 'margin-top': -(this.outerHeight() / 2) }` but if this appears too low the there is a problem with your outerheight calculation - try window.logging the outer height to see if it is 400px when the position is set

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38153/discussion-between-kfirba-and-pete)

Answer (score -2):

if you're already using jQuery, why not use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) for the dialog?

anyway if you want to go the normal way [why not use the awesome position:absolute method?](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/)

this also applies to a div and is compatible with IE7+, with the plus of this being a CSS-only thing.

Comment: The divs height is unknown. Therefore, position fixed or absolute must be used. I don't want to use jQueryUI for this purpose when this there is no reason to use it